# Windows-7 forgets my network credentials

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I connecting (with my Windows 7 pc) to a Folder on another Windows 7 PC on our network.

I enter my network credentials and it works fine.
But it **does not remember** them on the next login, despite me checking the *Remember my Credentials*

And the credentials do work. Once entered, I can create and delete files with no problem on that remote folder.

This worked fine 2 weeks ago. In that time, I have had to rebuild my PC (Server PC has not changed in that time)

Any idea why not?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I may have solved it. Looks like a long standing bug in Windows.

use the *Windows Credential Manager*
When I load that it shows the credentials I entered, but *Persistance* is set to *Session*.
I added the credentials manually and now *Persistence= Enterprise*

[image]